# Conflict between schema in singleton DLL connection

Tags: c#

I have the following scenario, I have a dll (I'll call 'Y') that uses a particular dll (I'll call 'X') for connection to database, and this connection is made by singleton. When the connection is made, according to some parameters that are defined is the SCHEMA parameter. When I use this DLL from an application (called Application1 ) which also uses the 'X' DLL to connect to the database, the SCHEMAS are confused. For example: I started application 1 and loaded the database settings, when I call some method of the DLL Y, the database settings are reset to another SCHEMA. So, if I try to call the DB again, the objects I need are not in the SCHEMA of Application 1, but the DLL Y.

Comment: Easy to understand if you share code

Comment: Call the programmer that worked on X and hammer out between the two of you what this dbase needs to look like.  Nobody here can do this for you.

Comment: //Initialize DB connection to SCHEMA DMN_X
                AppServiceProvider.Initialize(GetConfig());
                //Call one procedure in DMN_X.SOME_PROCEDURE
                ds.Load();
                //Here is where the other connection to DMN_Y.
                Alerta al = new Alerta(AppServiceProvider.App.SystemID);
                //Here if I call procedure SOME_PROCEDURE, the program undestands DMN_Y.SOME_PROCEDURE
                ds.Load();

Comment: Hans, the problem is this DLL is legacy.  I think if i would run another two separates instances of 'X' my problem is solved but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many ways and searching to much I found.
The applications is running in the same AppDomain, of course the 'X' dll too.
Then when I separate the domains on the constructor of my type in dll 'Y', solve my problem, and the dll 'x' is in different domains, then the respective configurations is loaded according to the application that is call it.